# Configure options MySQL server was compiled with?

Tags: linux, mysql

I have MySQL server 5.0.67 running on a Linux machine.
How can I know what configure options were used to compile it??

I'm interested in the option **--with-mysqld-ldflags** in order to know whether mysql was linked statically or dynamically.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can see the configure options using the `mysqlbug` command-line utility.

In your shell type `mysqlbug` and you'll see a template e-mail for bug submission.
At the bottom end of that e-mail you can see the configure line with all the options your copy of MySQL was compiled with.

The `--with-mysqld-ldflags` is omitted by default and it means the server will be compiled dynamically.
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/configure-options.html

Answer (score 4):

It won't get you exactly what you asked for, but you can check if a binary is statically linked or not (and if it is dynamically linked, what libraries it is linked against) with `ldd`.

When the binary is dynamically linked, the output looks similar to this:

```
$ ldd test-dyn
        linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007fffce7fe000)
        libc.so.6 => /lib64/libc.so.6 (0x000000391f000000)
        /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x000000391ec00000)
```

... and on a statically linked binary, like this:

```
$ ldd test-stat
        not a dynamic executable
```

Answer (score 1):

Which version of Linux?  The details will be in the source package.

For Debian/Ubuntu based you can get the source package with `apt-get source packagename`.  Then look at the debian/rules script that runs the build.

Answer (score 0):

When I run ldd I get this:

```
root@hostname3 [~]# ldd /usr/sbin/mysqld
        linux-gate.so.1 =>  (0x00139000)
        librt.so.1 => /lib/librt.so.1 (0x00ba2000)
        libdl.so.2 => /lib/libdl.so.2 (0x00ae3000)
        libpthread.so.0 => /lib/libpthread.so.0 (0x00b12000)
        libcrypt.so.1 => /lib/libcrypt.so.1 (0x00bad000)
        libnsl.so.1 => /lib/libnsl.so.1 (0x00be1000)
        libm.so.6 => /lib/libm.so.6 (0x00ae9000)
        libc.so.6 => /lib/libc.so.6 (0x0099d000)
        /lib/ld-linux.so.2 (0x0097f000)
```

Does it mean mysqld is statically linked??

Comment: Nope, this means it's dynamically linked against the libraries listed there.

Comment: Oh, great. That's what I need because I have to add some UDFs to the server.
In the case a server is statically linked, how would the output of ldd look like?? (I need to check this on other machines too)

Comment: I've edited my original post with details about that.